# Загрузка информации из PHP-файла

Tags: php, парсер, smarty

Всем привет.

Есть файл шаблонизатора (smarty | index.tpl) и файл-обработчик, который парсит данные с определенного сайта.

С %sitename% берется также постраничный навигатор. Допустим, мы получили ссылку на определенную страницу.

```
$(".pager a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
}
```

Как мне перенести ее в PHP-обработчик, чтобы он снова спарсил данные с сайта на определенной странице и подгрузить в шаблонизатор?

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Без браузера никак. PHP не умеет исполнять javascript, потомучто javascript исполняется на стороне клиента. Есть так называемый Server Side JavaScript, но не думаю, что он тут подходит.

Comment: @Drimean, а какие варианты решения есть? Пока что, кроме как записать данные в json и снова внести всю хтмл-разметку в html() функцию jQuery ничего не придумал ;(

Answer (score 1):

Можно номер страницы внести в data-page

```
<a href="#" data-page="X">Ссылка</a>
```

Потом брать ее с помощью jQuery :

```
var page = $(this).attr("data-page");
```

Отправляем ее на сервер:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "get",
  url: "/getData.php",
  data: {page: page},
  cache: false,
  success: function(response){
    $('#targetDiv').html(response);
  }
});
```

где #targetDiv - обновляемый полученными данными элемент страницы.

Или тупо загрузить страницу в iframe :D